# Extracting name and value from the enum

Tags: java, enum

I wrote the below enum from which I need to extract the name and its value:

```
public enum UserEnum {
    TreeUser("/tree"), ParentUser("/parent");

    private String value;

    UserEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

This is the way I am using the above `UserEnum` in my code base:

```
// extract TreeUser
String nameOfTree = UserEnum.TreeUser.name();
String valueOfTree = UserEnum.TreeUser.value();

// extract ParentUser   
String nameOfParent = UserEnum.ParentUser.name();
String valueOfParent = UserEnum.ParentUser.value(); 

// and I am using UserEnum this way as well to make name1=value1,name2=value2   
String mapping = UserEnum.TreeUser.name() + "="
                + UserEnum.TreeUser.value() + "," + UserEnum.ParentUser.name() + "="
                + UserEnum.ParentUser.value();
```

I am opting for a review to see whether I can simplify anything in my enum.

Comment: @Vogel612 This is the actual Enum I have in my code. And those are the ways I am using Enum in my code base. I just need to extract name and value from the Enum.

Comment: *facepalm* I should maybe read up on enums again... I had getName() in the back of my head and was expecting that instead. Thank you for clarifying

Comment: You do realize that the `name()` of an `Enum` is literally the name used for the values, i.e. `TreeUser.name().equals("TreeUser"); // true` and `ParentUser.name().equals("ParentUser"); // true` ?

Comment: @h.j.k. Yes I do realize that? Is there anything wrong I did in my above usages?

Comment: @user2809564 I see you have accepted @thepace's answer to use `toString()`, that's what I'll recommend too. :)

Comment: Yeah that is the thing which simplifies my usage slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the usage of `nameOfTree` , `nameOfParent` and same for the value. But one thing to simplify your `mapping` and provide a representation for your enum is:

```
public String toString(){
    return  this.name() + "=" + this.value()
}

// and mapping cna be written as.
String mapping = UserEnum.TreeUser.toString() +  "," + UserEnum.ParentUser.toString();
String mapping = UserEnum.TreeUser +  "," + UserEnum.ParentUser; // toString() is called implictly.
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for something completely different.

Currently you are putting settings into your code... hardcoded.
You should try not to mix up Logic and Data. It might be very favorable to instead use something like a properties-file, which follows the same syntax as your `mapping`:

```
Properties userDirectories = new Properties();
userDirectories.load(configuration);
for (String user : userDirectories.propertyNames()) {
    String dir = userDirectories.get(user);
     //use this instead
}
```